Every disjoint union $A\sqcup A$ of two same connected sets is disconnected?
Since the sets are the same we may consider $A\sqcup A = A\times\{1,0\}$.
Now, if we are working on the usual product topology, the answer to this will depend on what topology is used in $\{1,0\}$.
If it is the discrete topology, then $A \sqcup A = A\times\{1\}\cup A\times\{0\}$ disjoint  union of open sets, thus it is disconnected.
If it is the trivial topology then the previous union wouldn't be open thus it would be connected.
Is this reasonament correct? Thanks!

Disjoint union of any two nonempty spaces is disconnected, whether or not they're connected.

In this context, the "disjoint union" of two topological spaces $A$ and $B$ actually means their coproduct in the sense of category theory; it doesn't just mean the disjoint union of the underlying sets equipped with any old topology. Therefore, you are misreading the statement that $A\sqcup A$ is disconnected if $A$ is connected.

As Randall points out, the conclusion is almost true. See my comment on the answer below.

The topology on $X\sqcup Y$ is defined as $A$ is open iff $A\cap X$ is open in $X$ and $A\cap Y$ is open in $Y$.
Thus, $U$ is open in $A\sqcup A=A\times\{0,1\}$ iff $U\cap(A\times\{0\})$ is open in $A\times\{0\}$ and $U\cap(A\times\{1\})$ is open in $A\times\{1\}$.
Thus, $A\times\{0\}$ is open (its intersections are the full set and the empty set), and so $A\sqcup A$ is disconnected. In fact, in general, $X\sqcup Y$ has disjoint open sets $X$ and $Y$ and their union is the full set so it is disconnected.
Hope this helps. :)

Slight correction: $X\sqcup Y$ is disconnected if $X$ and $Y$ are non-empty, so $A\sqcup A$ is disconnected if and only if $A$ is non-empty.

@CameronBuie: Fair point.

@CameronBuie "Debate rages over whether the empty space is connected." If you choose the (IMO more convenient) convention that the empty space is disconnected, then the statement is true unmodified.

That's very interesting! @Dennis provided some good food for thought.
